# Communication between Webservice and Apache-Ignite in Different Pods in Opnshift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, ignite, openshift-origin

We deployed rest web-service on Jboss-eap-7 and Apache ignite on openshift.
They are deployed as different services in different pods.

My web-service is not able to hit the Apache ignite which is deployed in openshift.

In rest web service we are creating a client node and tries to put some data into cache but this is not able to find the running ignite nodes in Openshift.

How can we achieve this any suggestions?

Comment: How do the two know about each other? What is the service name of the back end and what hostname are you using in the front end to contact it?

Comment: You should provide more information about the issue. How do you start server and client nodes? What is your configuration? What exactly do you mean by "not able to find"? Did you check the logs and are there any pointers? Etc.